# Why does Java's Stream.reduce method take an identity element instead of a default result?

Tags: java, java-stream

Stream has three reduce methods:

1. `Optional<T> reduce​(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`
2. `T reduce​(T identity,BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`
3. `<U> U reduce​(U identity,BiFunction<U,​T,​U> accumulator,BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`

Methods 2 and 3 take an identity element.

As explained in Oracles [doc on reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html): "The identity element is both the initial value of the reduction and the default result if there are no elements in the stream."

I understand the purpose as a default value: this way the methods do not have to return an Optional. But why is the identity element used as an initial value of the reduction? What is its purpose? Why doesn't it start with first element of the stream as the first reduce method does?

Or asked in another way: why do the second and third reduce methods not take a default value instead of an identity element? This would certainly increase the flexibility because the default value would not have to be the identity value of the operator.

Comment: If you want a default value only, use the first one: `reduce​(...).orElse(defaultValue)`

Answer (score 3):

Look in particular at the third method: Here the accumulation (wrong word, really; this is a conclist more than a conslist, but I hope you follow the meaning here) is a different type than the stream.

For example, you have a stream of strings, and you reduce it into an op that counts up the string lengths; the accumulation is done as an integer.

In this case, the obvious 'initial / default value' is 0, and you CANT go with the 'first value from the stream'; that is a string and not an int.

Note how this matches up with the types: in the third sig, the type of the initial/default value is 'U', whereas the stream is a stream of T objects.

Even for the first signature, and if the stream isn't empty, you very occasionally don't want to 'just' start with a random (streams are not neccessarily ordered; 'first' doesn't make sense for various streams, so, 'some value' is a better way to think about it than 'the first value', that's already a bit of an issue) value from the stream, but with some known value.

So, let's recap:

1. If you want to go with 'hey, an arbitrary element from the stream can serve as initial value just fine, BUT, I want to specify a specific default to avoid optional', then that's simple: `stream.reduce(accumulatorFunction).orElse(defaultValue)` will get you this.
2. If you want to with 'I have a specific value that serves as initial value', then, I'm having a real tough time imagining how that wouldn't also be the default value if zero elements are in the stream, so, you just use the second form.
3. If you use a different type as accumulation value vs. what the stream is from, you must use the 3rd form and you must specify an initial value, because an arbitrary item from the stream cannot serve as one; it would have the wrong type. As with the previous: If you specify an explicit initial value, that's.. pretty much always also the proper default value in case of an empty stream.

Thus they all make sense.

Comment: "If you want to with 'I have a specific value that serves as initial value' ... use the second form" - But the second does not allow me to specify an initial value of my choice, I have to use the identity value.

Comment: "you must specify an initial value, because an arbitrary item from the stream cannot serve as one" - but an arbitrary value of those that are combined could serve as one

Comment: 'initial' is tricky here; these are not accumulator based (once you say 'accumulator' and mean it in the literal sense, then there is such a thing as initial value, and any parallellism is out the window). You can't combine without some identity value. A combination could serve as one, yes, but, you can't do that without an explicitly specified identity.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is used when you want/need an identity value to start the sequence.

The third method is used when the reduced value is of a difference type than the values being accumulated. E.g. could be used to add values to a collection-type object, or could be used to aggregate more complex values such as an average value, which needs both a sum and a count.

If you want a default value only, use the first one:

```
reduce​(...).orElse(defaultValue)
```

As you can see, there is a method for default value. If you changed the second method is have default value, but not an initial value, then you'd be out of luck if you actually needed an initial value. Those 3 methods gives you more flexibility than what you're proposing.

Comment: "The second method is used when you want/need an identity value to start the sequence." - but my question was why would you ever need an identity value to start the sequence (and not just a default value). Do you have an example where one is needed?